# dashed lines in UIView ?

Tags: iphone, uiview

How to change the border style of UIView. I need to display dotted bordered line on UIView Class.

Can some one please help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `UIBezierPath`'s `- (void)setLineDash:(const CGFloat *)pattern count:(NSInteger)count phase:(CGFloat)phase` method. This allows you to draw dashed lines.

Answer (score 2):

you will be better off using a background image.
make the dotted image using photoshop or alike , import it into your project
and use :

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dottedBackground.png"]];
```